# Property of the Dini derivative

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:(0,1)\to{\Bbb R}$ be a continuous function and define
>   $$
> D_+f(x_0):=\liminf_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}.
> $$
>   Let $S=\{x\in I:D_+f(x)<0\}$. Suppose $f(I\setminus S)$ does not contain any non-empty open interval. Prove that $f$ is non-increasing on $I$.

I tried the case when $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$. For the sake of an argument, assume that 
$0<x_1<x_2<1$ and $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. Then by the mean value theorem, there exists $\xi\in(x_1,x_2)$ such that 
$$
f'(\xi)>0. 
$$
I don't even see how I can go on in this case which looks simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $y_1 = f(x_1) < y_2 = f(x_2)$ for some $x_1 < x_2$.  For any $y \in (y_1,y_2)$, let $x = \sup\{\xi \in (x_1,x_2):f(\xi) = y\}$.  Then $D_+f(x) \ge 0$, because $f(x+h) > y = f(x) $ for any $h < x_2-x$.  Hence $y \in f(I\setminus S)$.  Therefore $(y_1,y_2) \subset f(I\setminus S)$.

Comment: Because if $f(x+h)\le y$, and since $f(x_2)>y$, then there must exist $\xi\in[x+h,x_2)$ with $f(\xi) = y$.

Comment: Ah, I see. For the definition of $x$ in the second line, do you mean $x=\sup\{\xi\in I:f(\xi)=y\}$ or $x=\{\xi\in (x_1,x_2):f(\xi)=y\}$?

Comment: Sorry.  I fixed it.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that I = (0,1).

Suppose there is an open interval J = (a,b) contained in I such that $D_+f(x) > $ 0 for all x $\in$ J.  Then for any $x_0$ in J there f($x_0$ + h) > f($x_0$) for all h in a neighborhood of $x_0$.  It follows that f is increasing in this neighborhood.  So in this case f cannot be non-decreasing throughout I.

If there is a closed interval in I such that $D_+f(x)$ > 0 for x in that closed interval, then there is an open sub-interval of it, and we are back in paragraph 1.

Now suppose there is an open interval such that $D_+f(x)$ = 0 throughout the interval.  That implies that f(x+h) = f(x) throughout that interval. Then f is non-increasing here, and all is still well.

Comment: This leads to the question of whether there could be some isolated point in I\S where $D_+$ > 0, yet the function remains non-increasing.  The statement of the problem suggests this could be the case, but so far I have not been able to construct an example.